# How to embed ms access desktop form into a ms access web form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, web, desktop

Dear MS Access masters,

We tried to create Access Database for sharing, the original intent is to upload to the net so we create in Web Access DB, but pending approval so right now we access the DB via shared folder in company network. We create "Report" in Desktop Access DB Report because it is the only way to satisfy our need, link the report into Desktop Access DB Form "POPADLG" on "open Print POPA" button, and want to add the "POPADLG" button into Web Access DB, but when we open the macro for this button, no "POPADLG" option on "OpenForm" macro. What should we do to embed our Desktop Access DB Form into our Web Access DB Form?

[Different type of forms, and lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUs7C.jpg)
and
[Macro with OpenForm command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AId6p.jpg)

Comment: If you don't already have a working Access web app, I would not spend a minute on it. Access Web Apps are dead. https://www.devhut.net/2017/03/27/steer-clear-of-access-web-applications-awa/

Comment: Dear AVG, convertingl old web access database into desktop database is on our long term planning, but due to urgent daily requirement, tips on macros or alternate hack on VBA code for this matter will be a great help :)